# Java string equal to literal warning message

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

Why when I try to do the following: (in `java`)

```
if (reason.equals("time")) { // my code }
```

The IDE shows me this warning message: (?)

> Method invocation 'reason.equals("time")' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

I couldn't find an abstract explanation to this warning message.

Comment: It's telling you that at this point in the code, `reason` might be `null`; and if it is, your program will throw an exception.

Comment: If you know what a `NullPointerException` is that warning shouldn't be that hard to understand. Thus I assume you'll want to read [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `reason` is `null`, you'll basically have `null.equals("time")` which causes a `NullPointerException`. To fix this, simply swap the two: `"time".equals(reason);`

Answer (score 5):

It's your IDE being cute. If `reason` is `null` then you could well get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

A common workaround is to use `java.util.Objects.equals(reason, "time")`. That function will perform any `null` checks for you.

Although, for this particular case, the cool cats, knowing that the literal is *certainly* not `null`, will rewrite to the *Yoda Expression*

`"time".equals(reason)`

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: "Yoda Expression" - never heard it being called that before but certainly fitting ;)

Comment: @Thomas: I've added a reference which, at the time of writing, includes the Java string case.